# Cant find \node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v4\tfjs_binding.node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I have tried to get the tensorflow.js library to work for days now.

I have installed on my computer

- Python 2.7
- Visual Studio 2019
- Node 12.13.0

This is the steps I've done to produce the error:

1. Create empty folder
2. `npm init` inside the folder
3. `npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs-node`
4. created a `index.js` file
5. added 1 line : `require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')`
6. tried to run `node index.js`

got this error:

```
C:\Users\kim_1\Desktop\workplz>node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
             ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\kim_1\Desktop\workplz\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v4\tfjs_binding.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kim_1\Desktop\workplz\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs- 
    node\dist\index.js:44:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "workplz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: path name may be wrong, if you are using visual studio code you can search it

Comment: what path name? path to @tensorflow/tfjs-node? and how do i search with vs code?

Comment: Do you have the entry corresponding to tfjs in the package.json ?

Comment: @edkeveked yeah it is listed as "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.3.0"
  }

Comment: Can you try to remove node_modules folder and try to install it again ?

Comment: @edkeveked I just tried, with no luck :(

Comment: What happen if you load the module that way `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';` ( in that case you have to remove `require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')` )

Comment: @edkeveked I get a SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201586/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-kim-vu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the case:

@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.3.0 has issues with Node version 12.13.0 (source https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2341)

Had to use @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.11 with Node version 10.16.3

Answer (score 4):

It is related to the version of `tfjs-node`. Installing a specific version such as @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.3 will fix the issue.

Uninstall the latest package

```
npm uninstall --save @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

And install the version 1.2.3

```
npm install --save @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue with Node and Tensorflow versions.

You can resolve it by upgrading the `node` version to 16.13 and `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` to 3.12.0.

- Download [Node 16.13](https://nodejs.org/ko/blog/release/v16.13.0/)
- Upgrade @tensorflow/tfjs-node using the following command,

  ```
  npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.12.0
  ```

Comment: Mine Node.js version is `node:16.20-alpine` Still not working! Any solution?

Comment: And `@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.9.0`