# TypeError: trackerFn(...).registerTensor is not a function

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

**Here's my settings:**

- node -v : v12.8.1
- Python 3.7.1
- System Version: macOS 10.14.1 (18B75)

**Package.json:**

```
"@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.0.4",
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.6.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.2.11",
```

Note: Had to change to these settings to resolve [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621373/cant-find-node-modules-tensorflow-tfjs-node-lib-napi-v4-tfjs-binding-node)

**My file architecture:**

[image]

** My code:**

```
const readImage = path => {
  const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
  const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
  return tfimage;
}


const performTheImageClassification = async path  => {
    const image = readImage("img_to_predict/actual.jpeg");
     const mobilenetModel = await mobilenet.load();
     const predictions = await mobilenetModel.classify(image);
     console.log('Classification Results:', predictions);
}
```

**Terminal output:**

```
 (node:65191) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: trackerFn(...).registerTensor is not a function
    at new Tensor (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor.js:246:21)
    at Function.Tensor.make (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor.js:261:16)
    at makeTensor (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/tensor_ops.js:98:28)
    at Object.scalar (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/tensor_ops.js:127:12)
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.decodeJpeg (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/nodejs_kernel_backend.js:1513:38)
    at /Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/image.js:103:14
    at /Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:388:22
    at Engine.scopedRun (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:398:23)
    at Engine.tidy (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:387:21)
    at Object.tidy (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/globals.js:172:28)
    at decodeJpeg (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/image.js:101:24)
    at Object.decodeImage (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/image.js:209:20)
    at readImage (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/server.js:97:31)
    at performTheImageClassification (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/server.js:88:19)
    at client.search.then.then (/Users/cyrus/Documents/Code/01. Code/debord_slow_sender_meme/server.js:81:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same error and while I was trying to fix this error other ones came out this went on and on.. And I ended up having 3 different versions of tfjs tfjs-node and mobilenet.

And I think this error is definetaly caused by version mismatch. I fixed it by removing **tensorflow folder** under the nodemodules folder, then just ran

```
npm i @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

I especially pointed that out because in the first place I tried to uninstall only these two packages by running npm uninstall command and reinstalling them again, but apparently things are more complicated than this in the nodemodules world so you need to uninstall the whole tensorflow package because for exampe I had a whole different version of **tfjs-converter**, another version of **tfjs-core** , **tfjs-data** and it really mixed up so make sure you deleted the whole tensorflow package and run the command written above to install necessary packages.

This will automatically install the latest versions of both packages and those should be 1.7.4 when I'm posting this answer. Now it works flawlessly for me, I hope it will work for you too.

**Here's my package.json if you want to be sure:**

```
"@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.0.4",
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.7.4",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.7.4",
```